# whether oob is implemented in api 0.6 oauth 1.0a

Tags: api, openstreetmap

s /oob is implemented for request without callbacks in api version 0.6 which is min and max for openstreetmaps authentication. As per the documentation (in wiki ) the current version of oauth is 1.0a but when I tried /oob it is not working

OOB = out of band

Comment: Cross post 1: http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=29664
Cross post 2: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/40432/whether-oob-is-implemented-in-api-06-oauth-10a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, yes. There are even tests for it:

https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/test/integration/oauth_test.rb#L157